# Call a C++ function from C# and the param is a interface pointer

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ DLL. It contains the following function:

```
struct Message {
    int id;
    unsigned short messageLength;
    unsigned char* message;
};

class Listener {
public:
    virtual void OnMessage(Message* message);
};

void init(Listener* listener);
```

Is there a way to call the function 'init' from C#? I know you can use [DllImport] in C# to call C++ functions, but the pointers are giving me a hard time.

Any help would be appreciated!

### My Solution

#### C++ Code

```
typedef void (*MessageHander)(Message* message);

class MessageDelegate : public Listener {
public:
    MessageHander* messageCallback; // hold the callback funtion

    virtual void OnMessage(Message* message) {
        if (messageCallback) {
            (*messageCallback)(message);
        }   
    }
}

static MessageDelegate messageDelegate;

void initEx(MessageHander* handler) {
    messageDelegate.messageCallback = handler;
    init(messageDelegate);
}
```

#### C# Code

```
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Message {
    public int id;
    public ushort messageShort;
    public IntPtr message;
}

class Program {
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void MessageHandler(ref Message message);

    [DllImport("MyCPlusPlusDLLName", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void initEx(ref MessageHandler callback);

    public void OnMessage(ref Message message) {
        byte[] rawMessage = new byte[message.messageLength];
        Marshal.Copy(message.message, rawMessage, 0, message.messageLength);
        // some other logic
    }

    public void Run() {
        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(this.OnMessage);
        initEx(ref handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you should look into "P/Invoke". I'm not sure it'll give you what you want, but it might help you find what you need. (Sorry I can't help more)

Comment: You need to implement or wrap Listener in .NET. Maybe using managed C++. Another option would be to P/Invoke as "init(IntPtr listener)" and call it with IntPtr.Zero if the C++ DLL allows init to be called without a valid pointer to listener.

Comment: Do you have to call this function with a reference to a `struct Listener` created in the managed C# code or to an (already existing) `struct` created in your native code?

Comment: I am writing a native code with C++ for managed C# code, and the function 'init' is in another static library.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my poor English. Please see my solution and give some suggestions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues in your code.

In C++, your `MessageHander` is already a pointer (to a function). No need for pointers to pointers. Fixes:

```
MessageHander messageCallback; // hold the callback function
messageCallback( message );
void initEx( MessageHander handler )
```

In C#, you should tell the runtime you’re passing delegate as a C function pointer. The default is complicated, sometimes it passes these delegates as some COM objects instead:

```
[DllImport("MyCPlusPlusDLLName", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void initEx(
    [In, MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr )] MessageHandler callback);
```

Finally, C# runtime doesn’t know your C++ code has kept that function pointer. C function pointers are extremely simple things, there's no way to ref.count them. Your C# delegate will be garbage collected shortly after initEx call. When that happens, your code will crash the next OnMessage call, calling into a de-allocated object. You need to store your `handler` somewhere, e.g. in a static variable, so the GC will leave it alone.

P.S. If you're passing that Message one way only, it's a good idea to specify `const Message*` in C++, and `[In] ref Message` in C#. This will slightly improve performance, the marshaler will stop marshaling that structure back from C# to C++.